# Error initializing Python 3 related to random numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, jenkins

I recently upgraded from Python 2.7 to Python 3.6.

I ran a job on Jenkins and got this error:

```
21:00:58 C:\Jenkins\workspace\LoadBalancer>python -u C:\pythondir\addorremove.py site 14 add --delay  
21:00:58 Fatal Python error: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python
21:00:58 
21:00:59 
21:00:59 C:\Jenkins\workspace\LoadBalancer>exit 3
```

When I reran the job the error didn't happen again.

I searched for info about the error but other people have only had it in Linux, whereas I am running in Windows.

How can I avoid this happening in the future?

The server it ran on is on Windows 2008 R2 Standard. The Jenkins version is 2.53 (which is somewhat out of date but I don't think that it is to blame).

The Python version is: "Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32".

This is what I have from pip:

```
Package    Version
---------- ----------
certifi    2018.11.29
chardet    3.0.4
idna       2.7
pip        18.1
pypiwin32  223
pywin32    224
requests   2.20.1
setuptools 39.0.1
urllib3    1.24.1
```

Comment: Could you show the code that cause the error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think it even made it into the Python code because there's no stack trace.